# Can you die when your plugged-in mobile phone falls in the bathtub?

Tags: usb, water, shock

I have questions related to the safety of using mobile devices in the bathtub. I always thought the danger in dropping it or getting water on it is mostly to the device, not to the person, but a recent accident made me doubt that.

- Is it possible to die from the *charging end* of a high-power **USB charger** (which can deliver up to 20V) in the bathtub?  (The charger itself would not be in the water, nor would be the wall cable.)
- Is a **mobile device** dropped in the bathtub dangerous (to the person, not the device ;-) )?
- Are there known instances when a submerged mobile device **started to *burn?*** (After all, the battery contains Lithium which can burn under water, and Lithium battery fires cannot be extinguished with water.)

Comment: Not enough information. I don't read German but that article looked pretty short. Ultimately I don't think this question can be answered well here so I have voted to close it.

Comment: similar older case... death happened not because of charger.. but when phone fell in to water, the person tried to first disconnect the charger from the wall socket.. and there was damage in the extension cord cable.. and sad things happen

Comment: Deadly cheap chargers https://lygte-info.dk/info/ChargerIndex%20UK.html

Comment: @mkeith The story is just the motivation to ask. I could remove it if that improves the question. My questions are well-defined and answerable, aren't they?

Comment: @Jeroen3 You are talking about charger that have an isolation less than 2000V. That's not relevant here.

Comment: @MathieuG. Is it 2000V with 90% humidity soaked pcb?

Comment: @Jeroen3 Of course if charger PCB is full of water it is not enough. But all chargers will fail in this case.

Comment: In the absence of more information nobody can say how she really died. It is safe to say that if she was electrocuted or died from burns, there must have been a different power source involved because the battery alone would not manage that.

Comment: Leave it to the inquest. As far as an EE (on this site) is concerned, electricity of a certain level can kill especially if someone is submerged or partially submerged in water. Speculating how that may have arisen is beyond what this site is intended to cover. Voting to close as soliciting opinions.

Comment: @mkeith I asked specific questions; I didn't ask how she actually died. Rewording.

Comment: @mkeith See whether you are happier. I'm curious about the actual questions, even if the answers so far seem to indicate a "no".

Comment: One of my complaints about SE are ‘rules lawyers’ and their tendency to close Q’s too quickly, which is why I took a break from SE for a while (looking at you, Dave Tweed.) Rules lawyers, who in this case are *wrong*.  The OP reframed the Q to ask for theories on what could possibly have caused this. This is an important topic and unfortunately an all-too-common occurrence in this Alibaba and Amazon world and as such is very worthy of discussion. I voted to reopen and so should you.

Answer (score 3):

The phone itself can’t develop enough potential to cause a shock with burns - the battery is only 3.8V. Further, any stray currents would have been local to the phone, and would not have found a body path.

What might have happened is that she reached for the cord to plug in the phone, and she got shocked by the cord, and dropped the phone... and was not able to get the cord away. Very sad - what an unfortunate way to lose someone.

Then the underlying problem leading to this would be two things: a faulty charger, and a non-functioning or not-present GFCI that should have tripped.

Comment: So in your opinion neither the low-voltage side of even a powerful charger, nor the phone could kill in a tub. (That's what I was thinking all along and wondered if I was wrong all along.) What actually happened we don't know, and was indeed not the reason to ask, but you are saying it needed to involve wall power.

Comment: It’s not about how powerful the charger is. The voltage it supplies is only 5V - not enough to be hazardous under any realistic circumstance. No, the issue is a leakage path from the mains through the charger and to the cord. The charger failed to isolate the low-voltage side well enough to protect her from shock. There is a lot of bad charger hardware out there that is poorly designed and not properly tested and certified.

Comment: Always buy name brand chargers and also, (even though I don't do this) it would be a good idea to verify that outlets are protected by GFCI (aka RCD), especially those near pools and tubs and sinks and whatnot. If you own the house, every outlet should be GFCI type. If you are renting at least fix (or have the landlord fix) the ones in wet locations.

Comment: Vienna has lots of old buildings, many probably still with legacy electrical installations. GFCI is, iiuc, only required when tenants leave.

Comment: If I were a tenant, I would ask the landlord to install GFCI in damp locations. If the landlord declined I would do it myself.

Answer (score 0):

Articles on this kind of subject are always too short and reporters always underskilled to even understand what a voltage is.

Here are my points :

- 20V can not kill. Even 60V is safe (edited : DC in dry condition).
- If the cord could kill, the 220V should be applied on it as soon as a short circuit were applied (that's what water does). But do you think you will die puting a cable into your mouth ? Or short circuiting it ?? Nope. Charger are protected against short circuit.
- Can a really bad charger be so badly manufactured that a short circuit blows the AC/DC transformer and put the high voltage on the output ? Maybe but unlikely. I short circuited a really cheap Chinese USB charger and I'm still there.

So I have some theory :

1. Because no plug must be present near the bathtub, extension might have been used allowing the 220V/5V charger to directly fall in water.
2. The guy who died may have touched the charger being in the bathtub with lot of water on the hands.
3. Differential fuse that protect against current leakage should have protect the human. So no differential fuse present. Or bad electrical installation.

I am also pretty sure that reporters and even "experts" that talk about that can't reasonably say : "ok it's safe" because they have to warn non skilled people to the danger of electricity. But here we can speak freely and try to talk about physics and electronics avoiding mainstream fantasies.

So your two questions have the same answer : No.

Comment: 60V would not be considered safe in a bath tub I don't think. Death is only a remote possibility. But a shock is certainly possible with 60V. This is just an FYI.

Comment: @mkeith indeed body resistance in wet conditions falls under 1000Ohms according to the internet. That means 60mA that could cross the heart and that could be harmful. I edited the answer. Nevertheless, according to Wikipedia https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extra-low_voltage 60VDC lies under what is called extra low voltage.

Comment: There are chargers out there that are referenced to neutral/live (depending on which way you stick the plug in). However bad you think the cheap shitty pink USB charger from China situation is, I assure you it's worse.

Comment: @Dampmaskin  do you ever experimented high voltage being present on the charger output? I do not say it is impossible but I would need some real cases to change my mind.

Comment: Any electrical appliance can develop a fault and it's output can become referenced to mains and can thus kill. In the case of a cell phone charger, the transformer insulation can break down, especially if the charger is not made up to local standards and insulation requirements. The Y capacitor between mains side and low voltage side can also be faulty. There might be a blob of loose solder rattling around inside the charger and connecting mains side to low voltage side, especially if again the clearance between mains and low voltage sides is not according to local standards.

Comment: @Justme okay but then the bathtub story has nothing to do with these design problems. Insulation breakdown because of too small clearance or blob of solder will not lead to output become deadly because cable output is wet, will it ? Water -> short-circuit -> heat in charger -> and then ? Insulation is a problem with high voltage, how does it become an issue in this particular case ?

Comment: No, that's not how it works. The point is not that the short circuit is contained within the charger, but that the short circuit is inside the charger between unisolated mains side and isolated low voltage side. Thus a broken charger output is deadly because it has become mains referenced and has mains voltage at the low voltage side. Charging a phone with it means you are holding an object that is live with mains. Touching something that is grounded (like water in tub or radiator) means deadly current flows through human body, so it is a part of the circuit.

Comment: @Justme you say "because it has become mains referenced and has mains voltage at the low voltage side." Please answer this : how this situation can COME FROM the output cable touching water ? You are talking about major design issues that could have deadly consequences. But I do not see how these issues can be a consequence of water touching low voltage output cable of a charger that was previously working well.

Comment: Not sure if I understand. Output cable touching water cannot cause the charger to break and become live. But if the charger is already damaged and output is live, cable is dangerous, and if the cable drops into a bathtub it can kill a person in the water with current. Components can degrade over time, heat, mechanical shock and vibration, and then a safe device can become unsafe.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104918/discussion-between-mathieu-g-and-justme).